# When you allocate memory in a function, does it automatically free when you return?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
    char* sub_str(char* str, const int start_index, const int length) 
    {
        char* new_str = (char*) calloc(length, sizeof(char));
        for (int i = start_index; i < length + start_index; i++) 
        {
            new_str[i - start_index] = str[i];
        }
        return new_str;
    }
```

How will I free new_str because I have to return it?

Comment: Note that you need to ensure `new_str` is properly terminated with a null character, if it is to be used by any of the standard C routines that expect null-terminated strings.

Answer (score 3):

The memory allocated with `malloc` or related routines will not be automatically freed when your function returns. (In general-purpose multi-user operating systems, all memory used by your program will be released by the system when your program ends.)

The routine that calls this function is responsible for freeing the memory (or must pass that obligation on to its caller). The documentation of your routine `sub_str` should clearly state that it allocates memory and that the caller is responsible for freeing it.

Answer (score 0):

> When you allocate memory in a function, does it automatically free when you return?

It depends how you allocate memory.

If you use `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` to allocate memory then it won't be freed until/unless the program explicitly frees it (e.g. by calling `free()` somewhere).

If you use local variables (e.g. `char new_str[length];`) to allocate the memory, then it will be freed when the function returns.